# Buttons not visible on community record list component

Tags: community

The buttons are not visible on custom object's Record List component on Community. The layout shows the buttons in place but doesn't show on the community for any user.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should include the Record Banner Standard component in your Lightning page above (Using Lightning App Builder). The Record Information Tab component (Details and Related) only renders details from a layout for the record.
The Record Banner Components can include actions/ buttons.